# compute maximum depth of xml-tree

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What's the simplest xpath 2.0 for computing depth of indentation of xml? My variant isn't smart yet:

```
<xsl:param name="maxdepth" select="number(substring(concat(
'16'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'15'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'14'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'13'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'12'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'11'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'10'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'09'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'08'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'07'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'06'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'05'[count(current()/*/*/*/*/*)>0],
'04'[count(current()/*/*/*/*)>0],
'03'[count(current()/*/*/*)>0],
'02'[count(current()/*/*)>0],
'01'[count(current()/*)>0])
,1,2)
)"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
max(//node()[not(node())]/count(ancestor-or-self::node()))
```

This produces the maximum depth of all the depths of the leaf nodes in an XML document, including the document node (`/`) at level 1.

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "max(//node()[not(node())]/count(ancestor-or-self::node()))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<root>
   <x>This is:</x>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c>hello</c>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c1>world</c1>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>!</b>
   </a>
   <y>The End</y>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
6
```

**Update**:

If the maximum depth of any *element* is wanted, use almost the same XPath expression:

```
max(//*[not(*)]/count(ancestor-or-self::*))
```

Comment: why not max(//*/count(ancestor-or-self::node())) ?

Comment: @IliyaKuznetsov, because `max(//*/count(ancestor-or-self::node()))` produces the maximum depth of all *elements* in the document. An element with this maximum depth can still have a child node (say a child text node) and this has depth that the elements depth +1.